# how to dynamically configure variables in transformation in Kettle Job from Java

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

In kettle I have one job. The Job is having 2 KTRs. The job needs to be invoked from Java call. First KTR is having first step as MongoDBInput . The query expression for step needs to be passed as input from java.

```
        KettleEnvironment.init();
        JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta("E:\\Job.kjb", null);
        Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);
```

How do i set the variable from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using:

```
 Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);                  
jobMeta.setParameterValue("inputParam", "urParam");
```

Comment: I am developing a web application which modifies the connections in kettle.properties and shared.xml at runtime, later when i run the job from my web application, the tool does not pick the appropriate connections from the kettle.properties file which results in exception like object not found, cause the tool starts querying in wrong db, any idea about that.